# 2010 27" iMac vs 2011 27" thunderbolt display

Tags: imac, thunderbolt-display

I have a 2011 27" thunderbolt display where the display doesn't light up. It's dead. Speakers work, screen still shows up when connected in displays, but nothing displays.

My friend has a 2010 27" iMac that most likely has a broken hard drive. I did a couple of ebay searches and the displays look like they are the same exact model.

I would like to take the display from the iMac into the Thunderbolt display. Does anyone have any info on this by any chance? I'm seeing that the display part is identical, but not sure if the connectors are. Figured i would ask if anyone has done this, or attempted!

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to swap out the display from the iMac to make a working TB Display? That would be unlikely to work. You can use the entire iMac as a display by putting it in Target Display mode. Or you could just replace the disk or run it from an external.

Comment: AHH. sorry. Didnt finish my question! You're correct. I could, but i would like to get my thunderbolt display running if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering the answer to this… The actual panels are identical, but the connectors on the back of them are different. Also the display mounts on the actual display are different as well. So in conclusion, without some insane modifications, this cannot be done.